# ViewFlipper on FullScrean image

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Sorry for my english. I have a gallery, when you click on a particular image, it appears on the screen. When the picture on the entire screen, I want to do what would it still possible to scroll. For this I use a ViewFlipper.
MainActivity

```
    public class MainAcTwo extends Activity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Gallery gallery;
ImageView bigimage;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.two);
    gallery=(Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            long imageId = ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds[position];

           Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FullScreenImage.class);
           fullScreenIntent.putExtra(MainAcTwo.class.getName(), imageId);

          MainAcTwo.this.startActivity(fullScreenIntent); 

        }
    });
}}
```

ImageAdapter

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ThumbsIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView imageView=null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(215, 200));
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);


    }else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(ThumbsIds[position]);

    return imageView;
}

public static Integer[] ThumbsIds={
    R.drawable.abs_icla,
    R.drawable.abs_dog,
    R.drawable.abs_flow,
    R.drawable.abs_neb,
    R.drawable.abs_rad
};
}
```

FullScreenImage

```
public class FullScreenImage extends Activity {

private ViewFlipper flipper = null;
private float fromPosition;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    long imageId = (Long) intent.getExtras().get(FullScreenImage.class.getName());
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imageView.setLayoutParams( new ViewFlipper.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    imageView.setImageResource((int) imageId);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    flipper.showNext();




}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        fromPosition = event.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        float toPosition = event.getX();
        if (fromPosition > toPosition)
            flipper.showNext();
        else if (fromPosition < toPosition)
            flipper.showPrevious();
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

in logCat

> 09-22 18:49:19.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-22 18:49:19.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.kruglick/com.example.kruglick.FullScreenImage}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-22 18:49:19.941:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1321):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>   09-22 18:49:19.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   09-22 18:49:19.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 09-22
>   18:49:19.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   09-22 18:49:19.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-22
>   18:49:19.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

my full_image.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/fullImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />   

         </ViewFlipper>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found two mistakes in your code.

1) You are setting the extras to intent with classname "MainAcTwo.class.getName()" and trying to get the extra using classname "FullScreenImage.class.getName()".

change the code in FullScreenImage activity to

```
long imageId = (Long) intent.getExtras().get(MainAcTwo.class.getName());
```

2) Implement OnTouchListener interface in "FullScreenImage" activty.

after making these changes your code worked without crashing.